# List indices must be integers, not slice while using json

Tags: python, json

Code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    edit = []
    file = open("wallet.json", "r+")
    for line in file:
        temp = json.loads(line)
        edit.append(temp)

    userid = []
    for i in range(len(edit)):
        userid.append(edit[i]["id"])

    user = str(ctx.author.id)
    if userid.count(user) > 0:
        await ctx.reply("You already have an account")
    else:
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title = "Blablabla", description = "Blablabla")
        embed.set_footer(text = "Blablabla")
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)

        entry = {"id": user, "gold": 0, "fyre": 0, "faction": None}

    json.dump(entry, file)
```

Json: empty

Error:

```
userid.append(edit[i]["id"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Essentially, I'm trying to make a json file that adds an object every time this Discord command is ran. You can ignore everything with the words "Nextcord", "Embed", and "ctx" in them.
When I run the command, the json gets an object inside an array. This causes my for loop that's adding stuff to the userid list to get a Typeerror, as it was designed to load a big jumble of objects, not arrays.

Inside wallet.json:

```
[{"id": "My Discord ID, in my real code it's there", "gold": 0, "fyre": 0, "faction": null}]
```

Another part of my code which does a similar thing worked flawlessly, so there must be something wrong with this piece of code. Please help.

Comment: Does wallet.json just contain a single line? If not, what does the second line look like? `[{"id"...]` or `{"id"...}` ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are loading the json wrong; and thus your `userid` list is empty.
The below snippet populates your `userid` variable properly:

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    file = open("wallet.json", "r+")
    edit = json.load(file)

    userid = [i["id"] for i in edit]

    user = str(ctx.author.id)
    if userid.count(user) > 0:
        await ctx.reply("You already have an account")
    else:
        embed = nextcord.Embed(title = "Blablabla", description = "Blablabla")
        embed.set_footer(text = "Blablabla")
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)

        entry = {"id": user, "gold": 0, "fyre": 0, "faction": None}

    json.dump(entry, file)
```

Comment: What's the difference between `userid.count(user) > 0` and the simpler `user in userid`?

Comment: You should use `with` to open the file so it's closed automatically.

Comment: This code doesn't work, my json will have tons of objects in the future, and json.load() only loads 1 object at a time, which means your code gives me a JSONDecodeError.

Comment: @Energia360 - Have you tried this code ? I think you are wrong: [difference between load and loads](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-between-json-load-and-json-loads/)